# How to automatically trigger a angular directive after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a print directive that is called when the `print="id"` attribute is in an `<a></a>`. The button is in a modal that is invisible to the user. So as soon as the modal loads I need the directive to go off.
Would it be in simple script at the bottom of the modal?

```
<a href="#" print="jobSetupPrintPdf"><button>Print</button></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
       ????????
    });
</script>
```

Here is the directive I am trying to trigger after the modal loads

```
app.directive('print', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            if (attrs.nopopup) {
                el.bind('click', function () {
                    window.print();
                });
            } else {
                el.bind('click', function () {
                    var html = document.getElementById(attrs.print);
                    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                    var stylesheets = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                        stylesheets = stylesheets + links[i].outerHTML;
                    }
                    var printarea = window.open('', '', '');
                    printarea.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
                    printarea.document.write(stylesheets);
                    printarea.document.write('</head><body>');
                    printarea.document.write(html.innerHTML);
                    printarea.document.write('</body></html>');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        printarea.print();
                        printarea.close();
                    }, 100);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

UPDATED

```
<a href="#" print="jobSetupPrintPdf" id="testing">Print</a>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#testing').click()
 </script>
```

Error Message

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

I am reading i need to add $timeout or a delay? I can not figure out how to apply it here

Answer (score 0):

Seems that all you really need to do is wrap the printing into a functions. Call that appropriate function right away and also use it as click handler if you need to still use the button.

```
app.directive('print', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            function simplePrint(){
                window.print();
            }

            function fancyPrint(){                    
                /* code for other window */
            }
            if (attrs.nopopup) {
                simplePrint();
                el.bind('click',simplePrint);
            } else {
                fancyPrint();
                el.bind('click', fancyPrint);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Keep in mind that if you have angular creating html in page you would need to give it some time to get everyhting built before printing

Comment: how would you put a delay on loading the function?

Comment: depends on page but one thing would help would be to use `resolve` of routing to make sure all data is available before template loads. Also look into `$timeout`. `$broadcast` might also help , send event to directive from other part of your controller code